# Splay Tree remove step by step

Tags: splay-trees

I am having some difficulties understanding how the `remove()` operation works step by step with the splay tree. My tree looks like so:

```
       2
     /  \
    1    13
         /
        10
       /
      9
     /
    5
```

now I want to `remove(10)` and get the following tree (9 is the previous item from in-order traversal, so I replace 9 with 10)

```
       2
     /  \
    1    13
         /
        9
       /
      5
```

is that correct so far or do I need to splay already before remove?
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**Update**
Or do I need to find the `10` to remove it and when found I already need to splay it up to the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [splay tree paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf) presented two variations for delete:

- The first will splay at the node $x$ to be removed then **join** its left and right trees. The join operation will splay $z$, the largest element of $x$'s left subtree, so it will be the root. Then the right subtree of $x$ will be the right subtree of $z$.
- In the second variant, let $y$ be the parent of the node to be removed $x$. First remove $x$ and replace it with the root of the tree created by joining its two subtree, where joining is the same as the one in the first approach. Then finally splay node $y$.

Your idea of splaying the node first before it is removed, follows the first approach. You just have to fix the tree by joining the left and right subtrees of the root after.

You can do some simulations here: [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/SplayTree.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/SplayTree.html)

Answer (score 0):

The deletion operation is exactly the same as in standard BST:

- first, find the node $x$ to be deleted (either via a pointer or doing classic binary search);
- if $x$ has no child, just delete it;
- if $x$ has only one child $y$, then replace $x$ with the subtree rooted in $y$ and remove $x$;
- otherwise you can do the following:

  - either extract the leftmost node $y$ in the right child and replace $x$ with $y$;
  - or extract the rightmost node $y$ in the left child and replace $x$ with $y$;
  - or delete $x$ and join its two children.

In your example, the node $10$ has only one child, so your operation is correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Nathaniel but should I not do any "zig-zag rotation" already after I've found node `x`? Because `find` is an operation and apparently I should rotate after each operation? (described here: http://www.btechsmartclass.com/data_structures/splay-trees.html)